# Reading binary file issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

I'm stuck with decoding using Huffman algorithm. For short in decompression section ifstream reads the value of 0x1A as -1 which indicates the end of file. How come?

```
ifstream compressed_file;
buffer = compressed_file.get();
```

Comment: have you opened your stream in binary mode (```std::ios::binary```)? also, `get()` returns `EOF` (which is -1 usually), you reached the end of the file.

Comment: You should probably share a bit more of your code. Clearly, C++ is capable of opening binary files and decoding huffman-encoded data, so the problem lies in something you haven't shared with us.

Comment: `ifstream::get` returns an `int` which should be compared with `eof()` value (that is typically -1) and then cast to `char`. In your code snippet no file is opened so reading from stream is not possible and it will only give you EOF.

Comment: Some operating systems use 0x1a (Ctrl-Z) to indicate the end of a *text file*.  Try opening your file with `ios::binary` mode.

Comment: Your code doesn't open a file.

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some operating systems, such as Windows, use Ctrl-Z (0x1A) to represent the end of *text* files.

Try opening in binary mode:

```
ifstream compressed_file("My_File.dat", ios::binary);
compressed_file.read(buffer, quantity);
```

Binary mode means to not apply any translations to the data read from the input file.

Comment: It actually worked with only adding "ios::binary" argument. Thanks a lot!